What is the limit value for the gain of a transimpedance amplifier?
Consider the following schematic of a transimpedance amplifier and a subsequent voltage buffer.

Now here \$R_{1}\$ is 50 GΩ, which gives us a "gain" of \$50 \times 10^{9}\$ V/A. Regardless of the fact that we cannot calculate the gain in decibels due to the units, I will calculate the gain in decibels anyway and receive 214 dB, which is a lot more than the open-loop gain of most op-amps.
My question is why will this circuit still work and how is the open-loop gain related to the maximum gain of a transimpedance amplifier i.e. how large can the resistor \$R_{1}\$ be?
Is it because the amplification of the differential voltage input is limited by the open-loop gain and not the voltage or current at the inverting input?

Gain and time and S/N are part of the question. I've made precision measurements at under 10 fA. But noise was above 600 aA and measurement period was 10 samples per second.

@periblepsis The resulting gain with a resistor of 50 GΩ is enough. Higher value resistors were hard to come by and a T-network comes with other downsides. Your S/N and sample rate are sufficient. Do you have any recommendations on how to achieve this?

The input current of some op-amps is very close to zero, take for example, the ADA4530 which has guaranteed input bias current of less than 20fA and offset voltage of less than 50uV. Also voltage gain of 120dB minimum.
The current gain of this amplifier is almost infinite. Input resistance is specified as >100TΩ, which will slightly increase the noise but it's >2000 times  the feedback resistor so it can be ignored with the relatively low value of 50GΩ as Rf.
Input bias current is 20fA which represents an output error of 1mV, so it dominates the error in this situation. The output can be driven anywhere within the +/-2.5V range by +/-2.5uV change at the input (voltage gain of 120dB minimum, typical is higher). A 2.5uV change in a 50GΩ||100TΩ ~= 50GΩ resistance is \$5 × 10^{-17} A. \$. The amplifier can drive say 10mA, so the closed-loop current gain would be something like 280dB. Open loop would be more than 66dB higher.

You have calculated a quantity which you acknowledge is meaningless and then compare it to something else. So the comparison is also meaningless.
The practical limit for the feedback resistor is determined by the offset current of the op amp. If the feedback resistor is too large the op amp will be saturated even with zero input current.

Thank you for your answer. What is the practical limit if the offset current of the operational amplifier is very small? Is there any relation with the open-loop gain?

Another practical limit is the voltage gain of the amplifier. If the V gain isn't high enough, then the virtual ground at the input won't be at 0 V and the transimpedance won't be 50 GΩ.
Input leakage (if constant) won't limit the (small signal) gain -- e.g. d(VOUT)/d(I_IN), but will create an offset (of ILEAK*50G).
In practice, 50 GΩ is difficult to use; typically some attenuation stages would be used to achieve more consistent performance.
